# VBA to automate google search

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am using below mentioned VBA Script to automate google search(Required results only in English), but getting error 91,Plz suggest solution.Other requirement is I require non personalized google search result

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_en&cr=countryUS&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

            Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
        Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)


        str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
        str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

        Cells(i, 2) = str_text
        Cells(i, 3) = link.href
        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here: Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")

If there is no "**rso**" id, objResultDiv will be Nothing and code will later fail with "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

(The actual error will point to the next line because although objResultDiv is nothing, the error won't happen till you try to evaluate it.)

So you need to ask yourself, what am I really looking for?

One way to avoid the RTE is to test the value of objResultDiv:

```
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
If Not objResultDiv is Nothing then
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)

    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

    Cells(i, 2) = str_text
    Cells(i, 3) = link.href
End If
DoEvents
```

This of course merely pushes the issue a line further down: what if objResultDiv has a value but objH3 does not? However, it points towards the real solution: what are you trying to achieve? And what are you expecting to see when you achieve it?

Anyway, that is why you are getting the RTE 91.

As for a non-personalised search, a quick Google (ironic really) suggests "The 'simple' Google solution is to type &pws=0 at the end of your search query, which turns off personalization. This method has the disadvantage of being time consuming and, for beginners, difficult to remember." Of course, if you're automating the search it's faster. No idea if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the 'English' part, but the script below will loop through the used range in Column A, starting in A2, going down.

```
Sub ImportWebData()

j = 1
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

With Sheets("Source")

   RowCount = 2
   Do While .Range("A" & RowCount) <> ""
      CellName = .Range("A" & RowCount)
      url = CellName

      'get web page
      IE.Navigate2 url
      Do While IE.readyState <> 4 Or _
         IE.Busy = True
         DoEvents
      Loop

        Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        DestSh.Name = j

            Sheets(j).Select
            Cells.Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Range("A1").Select
            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                "URL;" & CellName, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
                .Name = CellName
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
                .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
                .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
                .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
                .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
                .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
                .WebDisableRedirections = False
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With

            j = j + 1

    Sheets("Source").Select
    RowCount = RowCount + 1

    Loop

End With
IE.Quit

End Sub
```

The script below will check to see if links are valid.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckHyperlinks()

    Dim oColumn As Range
    Set oColumn = Column("A") ' replace this with code to get the relevant column

    Dim oCell As Range
    For Each oCell In oColumn.Cells

        If oCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then

            Dim oHyperlink As Hyperlink
            Set oHyperlink = oCell.Hyperlinks(1) ' I assume only 1 hyperlink per cell

            Dim strResult As String
            strResult = GetResult(oHyperlink.Address)

            oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = strResult

        End If

    Next oCell


End Sub

Private Function GetResult(ByVal strUrl As String) As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30

    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.send

    GetResult = oHttp.Status & " " & oHttp.statusText

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    GetResult = "Error: " & Err.Description

End Function

Private Function GetColumn() As Range
    Set GetColumn = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
End Function
```